# Unable to start Activation.service in systemd after starting Network service

Tags: boot, networking, startup, services, systemd

I have one `Activation.service` which I want to execute during boot after Network service started successfully.
This is the `Activation.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starting activation service during boot
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/Neurotec_Biometric_10_0_SDK/Bin/Linux_x86_64/Activation/run_pgd.sh
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=Activation.service
```

The `run_pgd.sh` script is working fine, I have tested that script before loading in `systemd`.

But `sudo systemctl start Activation.service` is throwing error. This is the status I got from `systemctl status Activation.service`

```
● Activation.service - Starting activation service during boot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Activation.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-11-23 09:46:30 IST; 3s ago
  Process: 3015 ExecStart=/opt/Neurotec_Biometric_10_0_SDK/Bin/Linux_x86_64/Activation/run_pgd.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 23 09:46:30 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Starting activation service during boot.
Nov 23 09:46:30 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Activation.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 23 09:46:30 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Activation.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This log I got from `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit Activation.service has begun starting up.
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop run_pgd.sh[3158]: Usage: /opt/Neurotec_Biometric_10_0_SDK/Bin/Linux_x86_64/Activation/run_pgd.sh {start|stop|restart|log}
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Activation.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Starting activation service during boot.
-- Subject: Unit Activation.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit Activation.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Activation.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop systemd[1]: Activation.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 23 09:53:57 inch-desktop sudo[3155]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I am not sure what went wrong. Is there something I need to do

Comment: Read the second line of `journalctl -xe`. You programmed the script to expect a parameter but in the `ExecStart` line you do not specify one.

Comment: @WillemK thank you for your response, I'll check that and let you know. I think you are right the script expect one parameter which I was not passing that's the reason may be the service was not firing up.